# unique=true doesn't create index

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

```
Email = models.EmailField(max_length = 300, unique = True)
```

Doesn't create an index on SQLite 3. Documentation says `unique = True` will create a index. But checking SQLite it is not created.

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to create index on unique=true field

Comment: Most databases automatically create an index for a unique constraint. Django only *exlicitly* creates one if that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Most database backends will automatically create an index if the field is marked as unique. Indeed, in the [source code <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.1.x/django/db/backends/base/schema.py#L1454-L1455) we see:

> ```
> def _field_should_be_indexed(self, model, field):
>     return field.db_index and not field.unique
> ```

So if a field is marked as unique, by default it will *not* be indexed, since the database itself will already do that.

This is the same for foreign keys, for which some databases will also create an index automatically.

Comment: So will it create, index on postgresql. If unique=True